# Invoke EntityDeploy build task programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, msbuild

I'm using Roslyn to compile, emit and run C# source code. However, I've run into a limitation when faced with projects that use EntityFramework.

It seems that simply emitting the compilation isn't enough, as there is an `EntityDeploy` build task that manipulates the DLLs after they've been emitted. (I believe it is embedding Metadata Artifacts in the DLLs after they're emitted).

In the `.csproj` file I'm processing, I see the following entity deploy task:

```
<EntityDeploy Include="Models\Northwind.edmx">
  <Generator>EntityModelCodeGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Northwind.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</EntityDeploy>
```

Is it possible to invoke this build task this directly and manipulate the DLLs I've emitted?

**Note:** I don't want to simply call `msbuild.exe` or run `MSBuild` on everything in the  `.csproj` file. The projects I'm building exist in memory, but not on disk, so that won't work in my case.

#### What I've tried:

I'm trying to learn how to use the `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation` stuff. I can find the EntityDeploy task, but I'm at a loss for how to invoke it (and for what parameters I should be providing).

```
var project = new Project(@"C:\Users\JoshVarty\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj");
//Get the entity deploy target? I'm not sure if this is a task or target.
var entityDeploy = project.Targets.Where(n => n.Key == "EntityDeploy").Single();

var projectTargetInstance = entityDeploy.Value;
```

I've also tried looking at the `EntityDeploy` build task as it exists on disk.

```
var entityDeployTask = new Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.EntityDeploy();
entityDeployTask.Sources = //I'm not sure where I can get the ITaskItem[] I need
entityDeployTask.EntityDataModelEmbeddedResources = //I'm not sure where I can get the ITaskItem[]
entityDeployTask.Execute();
```

I'm simultaneously brand new to `MSBuild`, `EntityFramework` and `EntityDeploy`, so please correct me if I've misused terms or come at this the wrong way altogether.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with `EntityDeploy`, but I'll give some information that I've gathered that might help you.

If you look at the [targets file](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#MSBuildFiles/C/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets) you can see that there's an `EntityDeploy` **target** which relies on `EntityDeploy`, `EntityDeploySplit`, `EntityDeploySetLogicalNames` and `EntityClean` **tasks**.

When the `EntityDeploy` target is called with list of `.edmx` files the following happens:

1. [EntityDeploySplit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.entity.build.tasks.entitydeploysplit.aspx) is invoked, it reads the `.edmx` files and determines whether the results from processing each one should be embedded in the target assembly or placed alongside.
2. [EntityDeploy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.entity.build.tasks.entitydeploy.aspx) is called on `NonEmbeddingItems` from 1., it splits the `.edmx` files and places the result in `OutputPath`
3. [EntityDeploy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.entity.build.tasks.entitydeploy.aspx) is called on `EmbeddingItems` from 1., it splits the `.edmx` files and places the result in `EntityDeployIntermediateResourcePath`
4. [EntityDeploySetLogicalNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.entity.build.tasks.entitydeploysetlogicalnames.aspx) is called on the files in `EntityDeployIntermediateResourcePath` to set the metadata `LogicalName` on each file to the logical name to be used for embedding (It's just the relative path to the file from `EntityDeployIntermediateResourcePath` with slashes replaced by dots)
5. [EntityClean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.data.entity.build.tasks.entityclean.aspx) is called to remove the intermediate files

I haven't tried this, but it should be possible to call these in sequence to get the expected behavior using the [Engine class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine.aspx):

```
 // Instantiate a new Engine object
 Engine engine = new Engine();

 // Point to the path that contains the .NET Framework 2.0 CLR and tools
 engine.BinPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
+ @"\..\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727";
 var entityDeploySplitTask = new EntityDeploySplit();
 entityDeploySplitTask.Sources = new ITaskItem[] 
 {
   new TaskItem("Model.edmx")// path to .edmx file from .csproj
 };
 entityDeploySplitTask.BuildEngine = engine;
 entityDeploySplitTask.Execute();

 var entityDeployTask = new EntityDeploy();
 entityDeployTask.Sources = entityDeploySplitTask.NonEmbeddingItems
 entityDeployTask.OutputPath = "."; // path to the assembly output folder
 entityDeployTask.BuildEngine = engine;
 entityDeployTask.Execute();

 var entityDeployTask2 = new EntityDeploy();
 entityDeployTask2.Sources = entityDeploySplitTask.EmbeddingItems
 entityDeployTask2.OutputPath = "C:\Temp"; // path to an intermediate folder
 entityDeployTask2.BuildEngine = engine;
 entityDeployTask2.Execute();

 var entityDeploySetLogicalTask = new EntityDeploySetLogicalNames();
 entityDeploySetLogicalTask.Sources = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Temp", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Select(f => new TaskItem(f)).ToArray();
 entityDeploySetLogicalTask.ResourceOutputPath = "C:\Temp"; // path to the intermediate folder
 entityDeploySetLogicalTask.BuildEngine = engine;
 entityDeploySetLogicalTask.Execute();

 foreach(var resourceFile in entityDeploySetLogicalTask.ResourcesToEmbed)
 {
    var fileName = resourceFile.GetMetadata("Identity");
    var logicalName = resourceFile.GetMetadata("LogicalName");
    //TODO: Embed filename using logicalName in the output assembly
    //You can embed them as normal resources by passing /resource to csc.exe
    //eg. /resource:obj\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed\Models\SampleEF.csdl,Models.SampleEF.csdl
 }

 //TODO: call EntityClean or just remove all files from the intermediate directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var mockObject = new Mock<IBuildEngine>();
IBuildEngine engine = mockObject.Object;

var entityDeployTask = new EntityDeploy();
entityDeployTask.Sources = new ITaskItem[] 
{
  new TaskItem(@"path to edmx\Model1.edmx")
};
entityDeployTask.OutputPath = @"C:\";
entityDeployTask.BuildEngine = engine;
entityDeployTask.Execute();
```

The output path doesn't seem to be picked up, but if it's empty then an error is logged. You can see this if you implement your own `IBuildEngine` and log the errors. The result of the process will be three files next to the edmx: "Model1.ssdl", "Model1.csdl", "Model1.msdl". These files need to be passed to CSC as embedded resources, at least that's what the original [targets](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/MSBuildFiles/C/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets.html) file seems to do.

Hope it helps, and at least gets you started.