# How generate edmx resources of my Entity Framework project?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to compile my c# project with roslyn and I need to generate resources files with resgen

```
resgen /compile Resources.resx
```

and then I get all ***.resources** file from my projects and embed to assembleis

```
myCompilationOfProject.Emit(ms,manifestResources :  ListOfResources);
```

but I have a project with **EDMX** file and find out that I must some resources that there is in this project ( `*.csdl,*.msl,*.ssdl` that is in `myDatabaseProject\Debug\obj\edmxResourcesToEmbed` folder ) .Visual studio embedded these files I saw these files with a reflector. I added these files to my compiled project with roslyn and it works well.

**I want to khow how visual studio generat theses file and from which file and which tools ?** I would generate these resources file programmatically in my **c#** code

Comment: You should check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952883/invoke-entitydeploy-build-task-programatically